# Can I pronounce the word "of" as /əb/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I understand the correct pronunciation of "of" is /əv/. However, in fast speech, can I pronounce it as /əb/ (which sounds very close to /əv/)? I feel like it's easier to say it that way, (upper and lower lips just touch), rather than the lower lip has to move backward a bit so that the back of the lower lip touches the upper teeth.

Comment: I'm sure you *can* but I would probably hear the difference.  "Can I get a cup *ub* coffee"  would sound distinctly different from "Can I get a cup *uv* coffee".  Of course most natives speak quickly enough that it sounds more like "Can I get a cuppa coffee?"

Comment: You could if you were from Bengal.  The Bengali language makes no distinction between /v/ and /b/, assimilating the former to the latter. See Abhijit Kulkarni's answer to this Quora question: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Bengali-people-have-some-common-Indian-names-where-V-elsewhere-in-India-is-spelled-as-B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard of a native speaker using /b/ in "of". To English speakers, /v/ and /b/ don't generally sound very close.

Simplification of the pronunciation of "of" can occur in fast speech, but the usual way this happens is dropping the /v/, leaving just /ə/ (as in the example given by Andrew in a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114352/can-i-pronounce-the-word-of-as-%C9%99b#comment230400_114352): "a cup of coffee" /əˈkʌpəˈkɑfi/. I believe this is less common before vowels.

Answer (score 4):

No, not really, because they sound very different to most English speakers.

The **v** sound in *of* is a [voiced labiodental fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labiodental_fricative).  That means your vocal cords move while you're making the sound (it's *voiced*), it's made with the lower lip and the upper teeth (it's *labiodental*), and it's a kind of buzzing sound (it's a *fricative*).

The **b** sound in *ub* is a [voiced bilabial stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_bilabial_stop).  That means your vocal cords move while you're making the sound (it's *voiced*), it's made with both lips (it's *bilabial*), and you stop the airflow through your mouth (it's a *stop*).

To me, the big difference is the fact that **v** is a fricative and **b** is a stop.  You can keep making a fricative until you run out of air: **uvvvvvvvvvvv...**
But you can't keep making a stop - it "stops" when you make it: **ub!**

If you pronounce *of* as **/əb/**, you won't sound like a native speaker.  If you say it very quickly, people might not notice, but if your goal is to learn a language, you should learn to pronounce it as the natives do.